# Laravel repository for recursive menu function

Tags: php, variables, laravel-4, controller, repository

I've been trying for some time to get my head around Repositories in Laravel but something is missing in my interpretations of various tutorials. I guess I'm having some hard time understanding the repositories logic. Actually I'm not even sure if I'm going te right way.
The thing is I have a recursive function to build a menu, and I'm trying to kind of abstract it, so I can use this more freely.
Right now, what I'm trying to achieve is a way to pass the variable $mainPages across every method on HomeController. I'll post somewhat the last incarnation of my code above. Hope someone can throw some light at me, about what I might be doing wrong, cause I keep getting an Undefined variable no matter what i try.

Routes.php

```
Route::get('{lang}/{slug}', array('uses'=>'HomeController@getPages'));
```

MainPagesRepository.php

```
namespace Repositories;

use Page;

  class MainPagesRepository {

  public function getAll()
  {
    $mainPages = Page::join('langs', 'langs.id', '=', 'pages.lang_parent_id')
            ->where('parent_id', null)
            ->get();

    return $mainPages;
  }
}
```

SidebarComposer.php

```
namespace Composers;

use Repositories\MainPagesRepository;

class SidebarComposer {

  protected $mainPages;

  public function __construct(MainPagesRepository $mainPages)
  {
      $this->mainPages = $mainPages;
  }

  public function compose($view)
  {
      $view->with('mainPages', $this->mainPages->getAll());
  }
}
```

Composer.php

```
View::composer('index', 'Composers\SidebarComposer');
```

HomeController.php

```
public function getPages($lang, $slug)
{
   $allPages = $this->getAllPages($mainPages);

   return View::make('index')
   ->with('allPages', $allPages);
}

private function getAllPages($pages) {
    $allPages = array();

    foreach ($pages as $page) {
        $subArr = array();
        $subArr['title'] = $page->title;
        $subArr['slug'] = $page->slug;
        $subPages = Page::where('parent_id', '=', $page->id)
                    ->get();

        if (!$subPages->isEmpty()) {
            $result = $this->getAllPages($subPages);

            $subArr['sub'] = $result;
        }

        $allPages[] = $subArr;

    }

    return $allPages;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's in your sidebar composer file --

change:

```
protected $mainPage;
```

to

```
protected $mainPages;
```

change

```
$view->with('mainPages', $mainPages->mainPages->getAll());
```

to

```
$view->with('mainPages', $this->mainPages->getAll());
```

You may also need to change your line:

```
View::composer('index', 'Composers\SidebarComposer');
```

to

```
View::composer('*', 'Composers\SidebarComposer');
```

Comment: why the * instead of the view name?

Comment: if you want the variable available on every single page, it's one way to do it.  I haven't implemented a view composer in a little while so it might not even be necessary.

Comment: Ok it all seemed to work. But I keep not getting the value in the controller methods. Var_dump($mainPage) get's nothing inside getPages() method...

Comment: I actually changed my question a bit. Hope my problem is clearer now. If you could take a look at this again I would appreciate it.

Comment: In your HomeController, the line $allPages = $this->getAllPages($mainPages); -- $mainPages is not defined when you try to use it as an argument.  The other thing is, if you're using a view composer, you shouldn't need to have that logic in your view at all. Composers pass the variables to the view, not the controllers, which I think is where you're running into problems.  In the controllers you'd still have to resolve your repository in the __construct() method and call $this->mainPages elsewhere in the controller.